# Illustrator CS5 Distorts Vector on Resize, using Scale Tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resize, cs5

When resizing a vector group in Illustrator CS5.5 with a custom made symbol in the group I get distortion of the proportion of the shape.

[image: Before and after distortion]

I've tried

- Tried resizing with selection tool holding down shift or option
- Turning off align to pixel grid in the transform panel
- Turning off align to pixel grid in the symbol option
- Checking Enabled Guides for 9-slice scaling  is turned on
- Checking Scale Stroke & Effects is turned off in preferences

Can you help me resize this without the distortion?

Comment: Do you get distortion if you turn off the 9-slice scaling? Do you have the object selected when verifying the Align to Pixel Grid setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for your help.
The problem was that 9-slice scaling and align to pixel grid had to be turned off for the symbol that wasn't resizing correctly. We'd turned it off for the objects but not the symbol - hence the distortion.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried grouping first? Maybe clear everything in the appearance panel?

If the curve is corrupt somehow, maybe running a path>simplify (with the settings turned down where it doesn't change the shape) will redraw the shape? Long shot, but it may un-corrupt it...